# Trace of stress-energy tensor for a scalar field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I'm trying to reproduce a calculation done in Birrell & Davies' book Quantum Fields in Curved Space (page 191). Given Klein-Gordon's equation $$(\Box + m^2 + R\xi)\phi = 0$$ and
$$T_{\mu \nu} = (1 -2\xi)\phi_{;\mu} \phi_{;\nu} + (2\xi - \frac{1}{2})g_{\mu \nu} g^{\rho \sigma}\phi_{;\rho} \phi_{;\sigma} - 2\xi\phi_{;\mu \nu} \phi + \frac{2}{n}\xi g_{\mu \nu} \phi \Box \phi - \xi\left(R_{\mu \nu} -\frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu \nu} +\frac{2(n-1)}{n}\xi Rg_{\mu \nu} \right)\phi^2 + 2\left(\frac{1}{4}-(1-\frac{1}{n})\xi \right)m^2g_{\mu \nu} \phi^2,$$
I want to show that
$$T^{\mu}_{\mu} = m^2 \phi^2 + (n-1)(\xi - \xi(n))\Box \phi^2,\tag{6.176}$$
where $\xi(n) = \frac{n-2}{4(n - 1)}$.
I've done the following

$$ T^{\mu}_{\mu} = g^{\mu \nu} T\_{\mu \nu}= (1 -2\xi )\phi^{;\mu} \phi\_{;\mu} + (2\xi - \frac{1}{2})n\phi^{;\mu} \phi\_{;\mu} -2 \xi \phi \Box \phi +2 \xi \phi \Box \phi -  \xi\left(R -\frac{1}{2}Rn +2(n-1)\xi R \right)\phi^2 + 2\left(\frac{1}{4}-(1-\frac{1}{n})\xi \right)m^2n \phi^2,$$
$$ =\left(2\xi (n-1)+ 1 - \frac{n}{2}\right)\phi^{;\mu} \phi\_{;\mu} - \xi R (1 - \frac{n}{2})\phi^2 - 2 \xi (n-1)\xi R \phi^2 + 2  \left(\frac{1}{4}-(1-\frac{1}{n})\xi \right)m^2n \phi^2,$$
using Klein-Gordon's equation,
$$T^{\mu}\_{\mu} = \left(2\xi (n-1)+ 1 - \frac{n}{2}\right)\phi^{;\mu} \phi\_{;\mu} + (\Box + m^2)(1 - \frac{n}{2})\phi^2 + \xi (\Box + m^2) 2(n-1) \phi^2 + 2  \left(\frac{1}{4}-(1-\frac{1}{n})\xi \right)m^2n \phi^2,$$
$$ = \left(2\xi (n-1)+ 1 - \frac{n}{2}\right)\phi^{;\mu} \phi\_{;\mu} + m^2 \phi^2 + \left(1 -\frac{n}{2} +2\xi(n-1) \right)\Box \phi^2, $$

using $\Box \phi^2 = 2\phi^{;\mu} \phi_{;\mu} + 2 \phi \Box \phi $,

$$T^{\mu}\_{\mu} = \left(2\xi (n-1)+ 1 - \frac{n}{2}\right)( \frac{1}{2}\Box \phi^2 - \phi \Box \phi) + m^2 \phi^2 + \left(1 -\frac{n}{2} +2\xi(n-1) \right)\Box \phi^2,$$

$$ =  m^2 \phi^2 - \left(2\xi (n-1)+ 1 - \frac{n}{2}\right)\phi \Box \phi + \left( \frac{3}{2} - \frac{3n}{4} + 3\xi(n-1) \right)\Box \phi^2   $$

$$= m^2 \phi^2 -2(n-1)(\xi - \xi(n))\phi \Box \phi + 3(n-1)(\xi - \xi(n)) \Box \phi^2.$$
I'm stuck here and I don't know what to do to the $\phi \Box \phi$ factor in order to get a $\Box \phi^2$. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is $\phi^{;\mu}$?

Comment: Integrate by parts

Comment: @Mass its the covariant derivative i.e. $\phi^{;\mu} \equiv \nabla^{\mu} \phi$.

Comment: @Eletie But why would I want to integrate by parts? I'm looking for $T^{\mu}_{\mu}$, not $\int T^{\mu}_{\mu} dx$. I don't understand.

Comment: @SamuelJaramillo, so it’s basically the partial derivatives.

Comment: @Mass, it's the partial derivatives plus a Christoffel connection.

Comment: @SamuelJaramillobo partial derivatives of a scalar is the same as the covariant derivative

Comment: @Eletie, you're right, but how can I get from $\phi \partial_{\mu} \partial^{\mu} \phi$ to $\partial_{\mu} \partial^{\mu} \phi^2$ in order to get the desired equality? I don't see how.

Comment: @SamuelJaramillo, Does $\Box = \partial_{\mu}{\partial}^{\mu}$?

Comment: @Mass, yes it is.

Comment: @SamuelJaramillo, I am afraid it is not exactly $\Box = \partial_{\mu}{\partial}^{\mu}$. Please check equation 3.6 of the book, written for the curved spacetime. Also, your last expression is the same as in the book, except you have an additional boundary term.

Comment: @Mass, you're right, but I don't use the explicit definition of $\Box $
 anywhere. What can I do with that additional boundary term?